# Redirect to Login Page After Password Recovery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login form, signup form and a password recovery form in my asp.net website. Also i have created login control, create user wizard, password recovery control in respective webforms. I want the user to be redirected to Login page after the password is being sent.

Comment: what you have tried? show you code, it will help us to get actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SuccessPageUrl** property as mentioned below :

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" 
        Runat="server" SuccessPageUrl="login.aspx" />
```

**as mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.successpageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :**

> it will redirect the user to the page defined in the SuccessPageUrl property
>   after sending the user a new password.